# Concatenate column names with non zero values

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

There is a table that have ID, event, date.

The current script counts events by id, event_type and date, transposes and then labels each ID by the combination of events types that day.

The concern is this breaks if new event types appear.

I am hoping to find a method that takes all the column names with non zero count and concatenates them. Ideally this method does not involve hard coding the events.

```
data test;
infile datalines delimiter=':' truncover;
informat id 10.  event_dt DDMMYY10. event_type $10. event $10.;
input id event_dt event_type event;
datalines;
1:01-03-2017:BB:b1
1:01-03-2017:AA:A2
1:02-03-2017:CC:C1
2:01-03-2017:CC:C2
3:03-03-2017:BB:b2
4:02-03-2017:AA:A1
;
run;


proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select distinct ID, event_dt format worddate. as event_dt, event_type, count(distinct event) as event_count
    from test 
    group by ID, event_dt, event_type;
quit;

proc transpose data=test2 out=test3 (drop =  _name_);
by id event_dt;
id event_type;
run;

proc stdize data=test3  out=test3z reponly missing=0;
   run;


proc sql;
    create table test4 as
    select event_dt,
    case when AA = 0 and BB = 0 and CC = 0 then 'No Event'
         when AA = 0 and BB = 0 and CC > 0 then 'CC only'
         when AA = 0 and BB > 0 and CC = 0 then 'BB only'
         when AA = 0 and BB > 0 and CC > 0 then 'BB & CC'
         when AA > 0 and BB = 0 and CC = 0 then 'AA only'
         when AA > 0 and BB = 0 and CC > 0 then 'AA & CC'
         when AA > 0 and BB > 0 and CC = 0 then 'AA & BB'
         when AA > 0 and BB > 0 and CC > 0 then 'AA & BB & CC'
         else 'Other' end as tag, count(id) as ID_COUNT
    from test3z group by 
        event_dt,
    case when AA = 0 and BB = 0 and CC = 0 then 'No Event'
         when AA = 0 and BB = 0 and CC > 0 then 'CC only'
         when AA = 0 and BB > 0 and CC = 0 then 'BB only'
         when AA = 0 and BB > 0 and CC > 0 then 'BB & CC'
         when AA > 0 and BB = 0 and CC = 0 then 'AA only'
         when AA > 0 and BB = 0 and CC > 0 then 'AA & CC'
         when AA > 0 and BB > 0 and CC = 0 then 'AA & BB'
         when AA > 0 and BB > 0 and CC > 0 then 'AA & BB & CC'
         else 'Other' end;
quit;
```

Thank you
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some might say, transpose and use arrays.

Consider this alternative -- instead of assigning the tag value by processing explicit columns across a row.

Compute the tag value while iterating through the id/date group, sorting and then counting the ids while iterating through the date/tag group.

```
* same as in question;
proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select distinct ID, event_dt format worddate. as event_dt, event_type, count(distinct event) as event_count
    from test 
    group by ID, event_dt, event_type;
quit;

* compute tag value (I call it type_list);
data test2a;
  length type_list $30;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.event_dt);
    set test2;
    by ID event_dt;
    type_list = catx(',',type_list,event_type);
  end;
  keep id event_dt type_list;
run;

proc sort data=test2a;
  by event_dt type_list;
run;

* count number of ids with same type list on each event day;
data want;
  do id_count = 1 by 1 until (last.type_list);
    set test2a;
    by event_dt type_list;
  end;
run;
```

You can add extra logic and `tranwrd` to change the type_list (a *csv* list) to a more verbose representation (contain words *and* or *&* or *only*)

Comment: That did it. Thank you.